# Watermarking an image with the text given as input

Tags: learning, web-development, web-applications, web

I want to create a simple web app where I can drag an image in, and watermark the corner with the given text. Where should I start for something like this?

I have knowledge in Java and Ruby.

Comment: Can you do the watermarking just in a simple Java program given the image and the text?

Comment: @Thorbjorn No I can't

Answer (score 3):

Start with learning how to load the image, draw some text on it and save it again in a stand-alone program.  The Oracle tutorial on 2D graphics would be a good starting point:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html

When you have that running , see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890659/java-images-receiving-webserver for the "upload image in webserver" part.   This can be a bit tricky.

Have fun.

Answer (score 2):

If you do this with Ruby on Rails in combination with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and the [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) gem it shouldn't be more than a few lines of code to get the whole thing running.